# asp.net chat based on callbacks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I'm new to async programming

I've read an article about chat on node.js and i tried to achieve something similar with asp.net mvc async controller

```
public void RecieveAsync()
{
    var list = (List<AsyncCallback>)HttpContext.Application["callbacks"];

    var tt = new AsyncCallback((message) =>
            { 
                AsyncManager.Parameters["result"] = message; 
            }); 
    list.Add(tt);
    HttpContext.Application["callbacks"]=list;

    while(!AsyncManager.Parameters.ContainsKey("result"))
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }

}

public JsonResult RecieveCompleted(Message result)
{
        var a = new { name = result.name, result.message };
    return Json(a, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public void SendAsync(Message _message)
{
    Dictionary<string,object> dict= new Dictionary<string,object>();
    var list = (List<AsyncCallback>)HttpContext.Application["callbacks"];
    foreach (var elem in list)
    {
        elem.Invoke(_message);
    }
    HttpContext.Application["callbacks"] = new List<AsyncCallback>();
    dict.Add("ok",true); 
    AsyncManager.Parameters["result"] = dict;
}

public JsonResult SendCompleted(object result)
{    
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

its working but still with this line:

```
while(!AsyncManager.Parameters.ContainsKey("result"))
{
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

its not pretty async , what else can i do , how can i achieve it with out sleeping and make my code more clear with same logic?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to write a lot of boilerplate code, why not leverage [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)? That is, if you are using .Net 4.0. It will simplify a lot of what you are doing, and I highly suggest looking into it if it is an option for you.